# Upload multiple files in android

Tags: android

I have used corinthian.js and cordova-2.3.0.js to upload files and however these scripts does not give me an option to select multiple files to upload to server asynchronously. iam a newbie in android development, can some one throw some light on how to get this done

Thanks in advance

Comment: This will help: http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/08/16/how-to-upload-multiple-files-in-one-request-along-with-other-string-parameters-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but i expected you will be helpful from [How to Upload Multiple files in one request along with other string parameters in android?](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/08/16/how-to-upload-multiple-files-in-one-request-along-with-other-string-parameters-in-android/)

Comment: I have tried that code already and it doesn't select multiple files and moreover it uses native android coding,i am looking for a solution in javascript for selecting multiple files at once